# Rust Partial Move syntax

Tags: rust, move

I am reading this [official example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move/partial_move.html) from rust-by-example:

```rust
fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    struct Person {
        name: String,
        age: Box<u8>,
    }

    let person = Person {
        name: String::from("Alice"),
        age: Box::new(20),
    };

    // `name` is moved out of person, but `age` is referenced
    // **What is this syntax here and why does it work? 
    let Person { name, ref age } = person;

    println!("The person's age is {}", age);

    println!("The person's name is {}", name);

    // Error! borrow of partially moved value: `person` partial move occurs
    //println!("The person struct is {:?}", person);

    // `person` cannot be used but `person.age` can be used as it is not moved
    println!("The person's age from person struct is {}", person.age);
}
```

This line of code:

```
let Person { name, ref age } = person;
```

caught me off guard; I understand,

`let person_a = Person {name: String::from("Bob"), age: Box::new(30)}`,

and,

`let moved_person_a = person_a`.

That line of code looks foreign to me.

Secondly, we are accessing `age` and `name` directly as if we have defined them directly in the scope of `main`. Does this have anything to do with the line of code above? Or this is how Rust works (i.e. Accessing member properties of a object without the presence of the object, which already sounds a bit insane to me)?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs

Comment: @Unlikus more than happy to take your comment as a answer. It is indeed what I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question is a pattern for destructing structs. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#destructuring-structs.

It creates two variables `name` and `age` and initializes them with `person.name` and `person.age`. Because of the `ref` the age variable will have the type `&Box<u8>` and point to `person.age`.

At this point the struct `person` is partially moved out, because of the move of `person.name`, so you cannot use it anymore. But you can still use `person.age` because this was not moves out because of the `ref`.